# kotlin opening new Activity inside of a Fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, imagebutton

Im getting an error on the second to last close brace.

Error: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

Im trying to open a Activity (TMs) from a ImageButton in my fragement (Dashboard).

```
class Dashboard : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

    view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.card1).setOnClickListener {
        val card1 = Intent(activity, TMs::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(card1)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function onCreateView does returns a View. You have inflated the View object, just return it.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View { 
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

..code..

return view
```

Anyways, I do strongly recommend you to init the clickListeners and any other UI logic in `onViewCreated()`.
So we proceed to create the fragment by steps, first we "inflate the view" which is on onCreateView(): View and then once it is created we can add UI logic (as listeners).

It would look like this:

```
class Dashboard : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var _view: View

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

        return _view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.card1).setOnClickListener {
            val card1 = Intent(activity, TMs::class.java)
            activity?.startActivity(card1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked I defiantly appreciate it, and doing the init to the clickListeners, I'm not to sure what you mean by that. I'm fairly new to android app coding.

Comment: I just edited it with a better explanation, if it worked please mark it as accepted :D

Comment: Ahh ok so what would be the benefits of doing it that way instead of the other way.

Comment: onCreateView(...): View is a very specific function that is meant to inflate the view, meaning in that function block should be only the logic to inflate the view and return it.
If we apply logic in onCreateView we could slow down the view inflation causing a "laggy UX".

Comment: Ahh ok makes since now. I defiantly don't want it to start acting laggy as this is going to be a fairly big app. So I'm defiantly am going to implement that Thank You.

Comment: one more thing im curious to how would i implement that code for more than 1 button that fragment?

Comment: follow the same logic you followed to create one button.
1. create the button xml.
2. initialise it on the activity. 
Same patter that with the first one.